# How do I make "Continue on PC" links stop opening in Microsoft Edge

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I recently downloaded the "Continue on PC" app for iOS, and tested it out. The default thing wouldn't work but clicking "save for later" popped up a notification that I could click on. However, it opened in microsoft edge. My default browser is Chrome, and there's no Microsoft Edge defaults that I can change to Chrome. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use EdgeDeflector

Here's a link to an article https://www.guidingtech.com/continue-on-pc-default-browser/

And here's also useful Reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/7g5ex2/continue_on_pc_opens_in_edge_even_though_the/

Comment: Reference and quote the content though and don't just post the link only.